# Как отправить ВСЕ выбранные значения select option value php mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, веб-программирование, mysqli

Как отправить ВСЕ выбранные значения select option value php mysql?
Код формы:

```html
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
  <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" id="genre" multiple="multiple" name="genre">
    <option value="Боевик">Боевик</option>
    <option value="Драма">Драма</option>
    <option value="Детектив">Детектив</option>
    <option value="Комедия">Комедия</option>
    <option value="Криминал">Криминал</option>
    <option value="Мелодрама">Мелодрама</option>
    <option value="Мультфильм">Мультфильм</option>
    <option value="На реальных событиях">На реальных событиях</option>
    <option value="Приключения">Приключения</option>
    <option value="Триллер">Триллер</option>
    <option value="Ужасы">Ужасы</option>
    <option value="Фантастика">Фантастика</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Вот сама переменная `$gfilm = $_POST['genre'];`

В БАЗЕ данных отправляется лишь одно значение, последнее. Сам код запроса
`mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO singles ('genre') VALUES ('$gfilm')"`

Answer (score 1):

Нужно всего лишь указать что `name="genre"` это массив `name="genre[]"`:

```
<div class="col-12 col-lg-6">
  <select class="js-example-basic-multiple" id="genre" multiple="multiple" name="genre[]">
    ...
  </select>
</div>
```

Вы можете преобразовать массив в строку используя одну из функций: `json_encode()`, `implode()` или `serialize()`.

```
$gfilm = $_POST['genre'];
$gfilm_string = serialize($gfilm); // Здесь используйте подходящий Вам вариант `json_encode()`, `implode()` или `serialize()`
$query = sprintf("INSERT INTO singles ('genre') VALUE ('%s')", mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $gfilm_string));
mysqli_query($link, $query);
```

Comment: тогда получаю ошибку, точнее текст Array.

Comment: Эти все данные, должны отправляться в базу данных

Comment: Ну это конечно все прекрасно, но весь код который вы привели в примере, это код формы) Мы же здесь не экстрасенсы, чтобы понять как, в какое поле и каким образом Вы это пытаетесь сохранить в БД.

Comment: сейчас изменю код. Но хотя бы примерную обработку genre можно? Обыскал весь интернет... А БД.. там просто.. INSERT INTO

Comment: @inorviga обновил

Comment: а как использовать json_encode()?

Comment: @inorviga Точно так же как и все остальное `json_encode($gfilm);`, подробнее можете посмотреть в [документации](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-encode.php)